# Explicit member function specialisation

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization

I am unable to specialize the template member function below. I have looked at the solution given to answer similar question on SOF but the solution that is proposed is same as the code I have below but it does not seem to work. I am missing something for sure.

```
    enum EStep
    {
         eStep1, eStep2, eStep3
    };
    template<int16_t iDevice>
    struct Device
    {
        template<EStep step>
        static constexpr bool isType() { return false; }
    };

    template<> template<>
    constexpr bool Device<int16_t>::isType<eStep1>()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<> template<>
constexpr bool Device<int16_t>::isType<eStep1>()
{
    return true;
}
```

Device is a template of int16_t, so to specialize it, you'd need to provide an int16_t value as the template argument. e.g.

```
template<> template<>
constexpr bool Device<999>::isType<eStep1>()
```

Comment: I figured that there is no "partial" template specialisation. I have to do it for the int16_t too. Thanks